# How to drag select multiple columns on highstock chart and have it reflect on the navigator?

Tags: highcharts

I have two goals. First is to be able to disable the default dragging on the main chart, and using drag and multiple select on the columns. second I want to know if it is possible to also reflect this selection on the navigator bar under the main chart. Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ma50685a/2/ here is the work in progress jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by using `point.select()` and `chart.events.selection` event. Here is a sample config:

```
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'column',
    panning: false,
    zoomType: 'x',
    events: {
      selection: function (e) {
        var xAxis = e.xAxis[0],
            flag = false; // first selected point should deselect old ones

        if(xAxis) {
          $.each(this.series, function (i, series) {
            $.each(series.points, function (j, point) {
                if( point.x >= xAxis.min && point.x <= xAxis.max ) {
                point.select(true, flag);
                if (!flag) {
                    flag = !flag; // all other points should include previous points
                }
              }
            });
          });
        }

        return false; // prevent zoom
      }
    }
  },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ma50685a/4/